# Are shaking legs something to be worried about?

Tags: infant, health, development

My wife has noticed that my 10 month old son sometimes starts to twitch his leg.  It only lasts for a couple of seconds, and is infrequent enough that I have yet to witness it.  She described it as uncontrolled shaking of the leg, and it seems to happen most frequently during feedings.

We had read that such shaking is normal in newborns, as it is part of their nervous system developing.

Is it normal that it continues to happen (albeit rarely) at 10 months?

Comment: Oh my this is what I'm going through with our 10 month old. His eeg is abnormal but still doesn't believe the are seizures? ?? I'm so confused. It's only in his sleep. And only one leg at a time. Did you ever get results? ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened to our daughter from 2 to 3 months and only when she was asleep. (both arms and legs were shaking at times)

Awake, in situations of stress, her chin was shaking like someone who feels cold and we learned later that it was the same cause.

As you said it happens to babies developing their nervous system.

But we went to a doctor (for a completely different matter) and it happened that our daughter was sleeping at that time and the doctor noticed the shaking. He looked very alarmed and told us this was potentially a problem (lack of calcium or some form of infant epilepsy, I forgot the name)

Shaking can be a lot of things: dream, some kind of stress...etc. If not frequent, I would personally ignore it but if it continues (or if you witness it and feel alarmed) just go see a doctor. Just keep an eye on her to see how it evolves and don't hesitate to consult is you're worried.

Comment: Agreed with this. The hospital told us that this is normal.